# What are some US Mandarin curriculum standards?

Tags: learning, teaching-methods

I'd like to start tutoring Mandarin through software I am writing. What are US domestic curriculum standards that I can base my teachings off of, starting at the middle- high-school level?

Please provide links and an explanation for why you selected a particular one. I'm looking for a curriculum example, learning objectives, exercise samples, and evidence of learning examples.

For example, I'm thinking [US AP (Advanced Placement) language curriculum](https://apstudent.collegeboard.org/apcourse/ap-chinese-language-and-culture) would be a good starting point.

If not, should I be using China's HSK?

I'm thinking AP because I'd eventually like to bring on more languages into my software and AP offers many language choices.

Comment: Any comments on this?

Comment: I think it depends on who are your target customers.

Comment: @emmaxl Ages 14 to 18 male and female students.

Comment: HSK is a graded set of exams, not a curriculum. HanBan provides vocabulary lists for each of the levels, but no information on required grammar etc. You might try sets of course books based on HSK, but I don't know how good they are.

Comment: Why limit yourself to domestic standards? Why not use international ones? The IB curriculum comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with AP Chinese curriculum but I would recommend go by China's HSK.

Reasons:

1. HSK is designed for non-native speakers and is administered by an agency of Ministry of Education.
2. If you adapted the HSK, you might lower your cost of authorisation. Even though I don't have the actual number, you could tell from the exam fees.
3. HSK is harder than AP Chinese. It's not easy to get 'A' in HSK.